# Activity already has an action bar supplied

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

Keep getting the error when I try to set Toolbar:

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
>   Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to
>   false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

I have followed the various guides and stack post of this but none has helped here is my manifest entries

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="Controller"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

the activity

```
<activity
    android:name="com.test.My_Activity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme.Light.NoActionBar"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
```

and the theme

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Does your Activity extend ActionBarActivity from the AppCompat library?

Comment: ya i extend ActionBarActivity I thought this might be an issue but what other activity has setSupportActionBar()? also Maheera if you look at my examples i already did everything in those links

Comment: What's your target API level?